# How can I convert C# methods to compiled expressions?

Tags: c#, .net, expression

I have the following class hierarchy:

```
public class Parent
{
    [DebuggerStepThrough]
    public void SayParent()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Parent");
    }
}

public sealed class Child : Parent 
{
    private static int _number = 0;
    public Child() // May contain parameter i.e. not always parameterless consctructor
    {
        _number++;
    }

    [DebuggerStepThrough]
    public void SayInstance()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}-Say", _number);
    }

    [DebuggerStepThrough]
    public void SayInstanceWithArg(string input)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}-Say: {1}", _number, input);
    }

    [DebuggerStepThrough]
    public static void SayStatic()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}-Say", _number);
    }

    [DebuggerStepThrough]
    public static void SayStaticWithArg(string input)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}-Say: {1}", _number, input);
    }

    [DebuggerStepThrough]
    public static Task SayStaticWithArgAndReturn(string input)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}-Say: {1}", _number, input);
        return null;
    }
}
```

I need to be able to invoke any of these methods for a new instance of `Child` at any given time using reflection however to improve performance I need to resort to `Delegate` and/or `Compiled Expressions`.

So for example I can have:

```
var instanceOne = new Child();
var instanceTwo = new Child();
```

for which I would need to at runtime invoke these methods passing the arguments for those that need it. Note they include both `static` and `instance` methods with some accepting a parameter.

I have so far tried the following for the "SayInstance" method:

```
var sayInstanceMethod = typeof(Child)
        .GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static)
        .Where(m => m.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DebuggerStepThroughAttribute), true).Length > 0)
        .Where(t => t.Name == "SayInstance")
        .First()
```

And then:

```
var instance = Expression.Constant(new Child()); // This should NOT be Constant, but then what should it be?!
var mCallInstance = Expression.Call(instance, sayInstanceMethod);

Action action = Expression.Lambda<Action>(mCallInstance).Compile();

action();
action(); // I need to pass in a new instance of Child to this method somehow
```

However I am getting:

```
1-Say
1-Say
```

instead of:

```
1-Say 
2-Say
```

I suspect this is due to `Expression.Constant` but I cannot figure out how I could let it accept an instance of `Child` as its target at runtime.

I am hopeless when it comes to `Expressions` :-(

I am basically trying to implement what Jon Skeet mentions [HERE](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2008/08/09/making-reflection-fly-and-exploring-delegates/) either using `Delegates` or `Compiled Expressions`.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: You incrementing _number on constructor. And it is static field. So, You will never have the result that you expected. Store the _number field into a private field

Comment: That's just the method for ensuring the end result will work. The main problem is that I am unable to create an expression that accepts the new instance of `Child` at runtime.

Comment: Are the lines `var instanceOne = new Child();` and `var instanceTwo = new Child();` ran in the same test that calls `action();` twice ?

Comment: @Mat They don't have to, that's just there to give you a better idea of what I am trying to do but it looks like it's more confusing than helpful! I have added the comment I hope it helps.

Comment: You are calling an action on the same instance. Shouldn't you be creating a new `instance`, `mCallInstance`, and `action` in between the calls to `action()` to get the second instance which will in turn increment your static integer?

Comment: Mikanikal's comment is why my question was necessary

Comment: @Mikanikal I shouldn't have to create that every time I want to invoke the methods on a new instance (this will be called millions of times for a million different objects), ideally I should be creating a `Action<Child>` (for void methods) that I can use to pass in the instance of the object and a `Func<Child, Task>` for the methods that returns a `Task`. But my problem is how I can get there :-)

Comment: I am reviewing the documentation on the 'Expression' classes but just looking at this I am with @Mat. Everything looks to be assigned to a single instance... Your first `instance` object. You have to reassign that at some point in order for `action()` to call a method on a different instance... When does that happen?

Comment: Actually, if all you are doing is wanting to increment the static variable then you don't need to reassign the object, just create new instances along the way.

Comment: I believe that using [Expressions.NewExpression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.newexpression(v=vs.110).aspx) will yield the results you're looking for, for the instance methods that is. The problem right now is that `new Child()` is Not re-evaluated when you call `action();`

Comment: @Mat, yes that's exactly what the problem is, but I cannot use `Expressions.NewExpression` as my instances may have parametrized constructors, I already have the process of creating my instances I just need to be able to somehow plug it in to the expression.

Comment: @MaYaN It's a bit hard to help without knowing what that creation process is, but in any case, [This overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb346083(v=vs.110).aspx) should still work.

Comment: @Mat Think of that process as a method that basically returns an instance of `Child` whenever you call it, It can implement it via `IL Weaving` or can simply come from a `IOC Container` that doesn't matter what matters is that I don't want to create it by looking up the constructors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you need to use parameters, like this:

```
var instanceOne = new Child();
var instanceTwo = new Child();            
var instance = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Child), "c"); // This should NOT be Constant, but then what should it be?!
var mCallInstance = Expression.Call(instance, sayInstanceMethod);
Action<Child> action = Expression.Lambda<Action<Child>>(mCallInstance, instance).Compile();

action(instanceOne);
action(instanceTwo); // I need to pass in a new instance of Child to this method somehow
```

Of course this will not output `1, 2` because your _number field is static and after creation of two instances has value 2 for both.

EDIT. If you need to call method with arguments - declare more parameters. For example if SayInstance has one argument of type string, then:

```
var instanceOne = new Child();
var instanceTwo = new Child();            
var instance = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Child), "instance");
var arg = Expression.Parameter(typeof(string), "arg");
var mCallInstance = Expression.Call(instance, sayInstanceMethod, arg);
Action<Child,string> action = Expression.Lambda<Action<Child,string>>(mCallInstance, instance, arg).Compile();

action(instanceOne, "one");
action(instanceTwo, "two");
```

Comment: You my friend, made my day! This is exactly what I need. Thank you :-)

Comment: Just me being greedy now! how can I expand that to also pass in an argument if I want to? e.g: `public void SayInstanceWithArg(string input)`

Comment: Pass as argument to "action" or as a constant?

Comment: Not as constant but as parameter, so yes to the action.

Comment: Updated answer with an example.

Answer (score 2):

Try this out, this workf for me for a parameterless constructor, but this is that you need:

```
var instance = Expression.New(typeof(Child).GetConstructor(new Type[0]));
var mCallInstance = Expression.Call(instance, sayInstanceMethod);

Action action = Expression.Lambda<Action>(mCallInstance).Compile();

action();
action(); // I need to pass in a new instance of Child to this method someh
```

Comment: Amazing! almost there however (despite my example) I need it to work with parameterised constructors as well, I already have the process of creating a new instance of the object, is there a way where I can pass in the object which I have already created?